# C# PHP-CGI - Calling phpinfo crashes webserver

Tags: c#, php, cgi, webserver

I created a simple and small webserver for only handling GET requests. I also wanted to add PHP support and also managed it. But there is one problem:

Everytime I try to call phpinfo() inside a .php file my server stops at "WaitForExit" Process.

```
 class FastPHP
    {
        private string _phpPath = @"C:\\Program Files (x86)\\PHP\\php-cgi.exe";
        Process p;

        public FastPHP(string filename)
        {
            p = new Process();
            p.StartInfo.FileName = this._phpPath;
            p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = true;
            p.StartInfo.Arguments = "-q \""+filename+"\"";
            p.StartInfo.RedirectStandardOutput = true;
            p.StartInfo.UseShellExecute = false;
        }

        public string getPHPOutput()
        {
            p.Start();
            p.WaitForExit();
            string sOutput = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();
            p.Close();

            return sOutput;
        }
    }
```

my PHP.ini settings should be fine, I adapted everything for fastcgi use. Any Ideas how to fix this problem?

Comment: May be a php module is defect. Try to disable every module and reenable them one after one.

Comment: What happens if you first execute `string sOutput = p.StandardOutput.ReadToEnd();` and after that `p.WaitForExit();`?

Comment: haha, thanks vstm! This worked out fine! I crushed my head on it and the solution is so simple! Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the `StandardOutput` has a certain buffer size. If this buffer is full then any `write()` to stdout will block. Now if you call `p.WaitForExit()` you are waiting indefinitely.

The solution is to first read everything from the `StandardOutput` and then call `WaitForExit`.